# Add new field to a specific object in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to add a new field to a an object after i search the specific object,
Database looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "608378ef1ae6b1368c6220c6"
    },
    "username": "paul",
    "password": "cacavaca123",
    "question": "q1",
    "answer": "cutu"
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6084c1b557f2242bcc629440"
    },
    "username": "mircea",
    "password": "123456",
    "question": "q1",
    "answer": "cutu"
}
```

And i want to search in db for the object with **username: paul** and add a new field **friends:[alex]**, I have tried this but its not working:

```
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        var dbc = db.db("chat");
        dbc.collection("accounts").find({username: { $eq: user}}).aggregate( [
            {
              $addFields: {
                frequent:[new_friend]
              }
            }
        ])

        db.close();
    });
```

Also if you know, can you tell me how to update that array of **friends** and add a new friend to that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use update query to do so

Read - [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/updateOne/)

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/mrTg0DKtnrW

```
db.collection.update(
{ "username": "paul" },
{
  $set: {
    friends: ["alex" ]
  }
})
```

---

Aggregation demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/yiJgkrgdeHZ